# Figuring out the time period of an Atwood system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

SO I was working on Atwoods, when I came up with the following problem, It is more complicated but i should understand this simpler scenario first.

As shown in the diagram above, (Atwood machine), mass $m_{2}$, is held up by a a small angle $a$,and released so I figured I could find the time period of swinging,

What I did was

$$T-m_{1}g=m_{1}a  . ......1$$

$$T-m_{2}g\cos\theta=\frac{m_{2}v^{2}}{r} ....1$$

For this case i assumed $m_{1}=m_{2}$,
 Combining the two equation

$$a=\frac{v^{2}}{r}+g(\cos\theta-1)$$

I used conservation of energy and $\cos\theta=\frac{h}{r}$ to get

$$a=g(3\cos\theta-1)$$

After this i guess the period of oscillation is dependent on the radius of rotation, which changes based on the acceleration, But of course the acceleration is changing, so do i have to use numerical calculation, or approximation of angles and what not? i prefer the latter.

and is my calculation correct?

Comment: First, your second equation isn't correct if the string is moving along the pulley wheel, since mass $m_2$'s motion wouldn't be circular. Second, you'll probably need to solve a differential equation to determine the total motion -- are you familiar with differential equations?

Comment: Yes I am, but I see to differential form in the equation, what I am not familiar with is langrangian

Comment: This seems like quite a complex problem to solve analytically without Lagrangian mechanics, unless I'm missing some technique; I'd encourage you to take a numerical approach. You state that this is a simplified version of another problem - what was that problem? It may be easier to solve.

Comment: Use action angle variables. This will fetch you the time-period.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite confused about your calculation. E.g. I think $a=\theta$. However, to solve this problem, the proper Langrangian is:

$L=T-V=\frac12 m_1 \dot{r}^2+\frac12m_2(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2)-gr(m_1-m_2\cos(\theta))) $

You can find the e.o.m. by solving the Euler-Lagrange eqns.:

$0=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial r}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,0=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}$.

This yields 2 coupled diff. eqns. which you need to solve (e.g. numerically).
For example the second equation is:

$0=2r\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r^2\ddot{\theta}+gr\sin{\theta}$

Good luck ;-) !